# What are the meanings and differences between "uses" and "rebinds" a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminology

From Python in a Nutshell:

> **Eschew global**
>
> Never use  global  if **the function body just uses a global
>   variable**  (including  **mutating  the  object  bound  to  that 
>   variable**, when  the  object  is  mutable).
>
> Use  a  global   statement  only  if
>   **the  function  body  rebinds  a  global  variable**  (generally  by assigning  to  the  variable’s  name).

What are the meanings and differences between  "uses" and "rebinds" a  variable?

Is "mutating the object bound to a variable" "uses" or "rebinds" the  variable? Why?

Comment: When you **use** a variable in a function, you are simply using the value of the variable or mutating the object the variable references. When you **rebind** a variable, you are rebinding the actually variable name to refer to a different object.

Comment: Thanks. Does "access" a variable mean the same as "use" a variable? How about "reference" a variable?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll post an answer in a second to elaborate on my comment above.

Comment: Does "reference" a variable mean the same as getting the object referred by the variable? Does "mutating" the object referred by a variable mean the same as setting the object referred by the variable?

Comment: Yes. it does. both terms mean the same in this context.

Comment: No! Mutating an object and setting a variable are not related!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If you're addressing my comment, then Tim added that extra question _after_ I had already posted my comment. The original comment I was referring to read _"Does "reference" a variable mean the same as getting the object referred by the variable? "_.

Comment: @ChristianDean: Sorry about that. Could you also clarify about "reference" a variable, "access" a variable, "setting" a variable, and "getting" a variable in my update to my post?

Comment: @Tim "reference", "access", and "getting" all mean the same here. You are getting the existing object to which a variable refers. "setting" means the same as "rebind". You are "setting" the value of the variable to refer to a new object.

Answer (score 4):

"Mutate" and "bind"/"rebind" are two mutually exclusive operations. Mutating changes an object, whereas binding changes a name.

This is binding:

```
a = []
```

This is mutating:

```
a.append(None)
```

"Using" means accessing the existing object bound to a name, whether for reading or for mutation.

Answer (score 2):

### Using a variable

When you **use** a variable, ***you are using the actually value of the variable - the object to which it refers -  or mutating the object that the variable name refers to***. Here is an example:

```
>>> var1 = 1
>>> var2 = [1]
>>> 
>>> def func():
    print(var1)
    var2.append(2)


>>> func()
1
>>> var2
[1, 2]
>>>
```

In the above example, we are *using* `var1` and `var2` inside of `func`. We use `var1` because we use it's value in our call to `print`. And we used `var2` because we mutated the object it referred to. Notice we didn't change the object to which `var2` referred, we **used** the already existing object and modified it. Also notice that we never tried to assign a *new* value to either variable.

### Rebinding a variable

When you **rebind** a variable, ***you are changing the object to which the variable name refers***. Here is another example to help illustrate the point:

```
>>> var1 = 1
>>> 
>>> def func():
    global var1
    var1 = 2


>>> func()
>>> var1
2
>>>
```

In the above examples. We are rebinding `var` inside of `func`. `var1` use to have a reference to the object `1`, but because we rebinding `var1` to `2`, it now refers to the object `2`.

### So what's the difference?

The difference is that when we use a variable, we are simply using the object to which the variable already refers. When we rebind a variable, we change the object to which the variable refers.