# Id of dictionary object showing different value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, object, immutability, mutable

What I have learned till now is a **dictionary in python is mutable**, ie we can change any value of a dictionary object without changing its object id.

But when I changed a value of a dictionary, and when I see the result, the id changes.

Here's what I have done.

```
d = {1:"apple",2:"ball"}
print(d)
print(id(d))
d = {1:"orange",2:"ball"}
print(id(d))
```

When I run the file, the result is as follow:

```
{1: 'apple', 2: 'ball'}
10188632
10188672
```

As we can see, the id of the object changes, but in my view id remains same as a dictionary is mutable object.

Comment: You are overwriting the original dictionary with a new one, so of course the ID changes.. If you change it via reference like `d[1] = "orange"`, the ID stays the same.

Comment: "we can change any value of a dictionary object without changing its object id" - you *can*, but you *didn't*. The fact that dicts are mutable doesn't mean you actually mutated it. You *replaced* your original dict.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was a blunder from my side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the meanings and differences between "uses" and "rebinds" a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384375/what-are-the-meanings-and-differences-between-uses-and-rebinds-a-variable)